# assign a form value in html to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

I am trying a small project with HTML and Javascript.
I have programmed 3 functions and want to call them to display a result using 2 values being input in a form.

I seem to be stumbling upon getting the 2 values to be recognised by the Javascript code.

I would be so happy if someone could point out what I am doing wrong?

Here is my project...

```js
//degrees to radians function
function degRad(deg) {
  var rad = ( Math.PI / 180) * deg;
  return rad;
}

//easting calcualtion function
function east(deg, dist) {
  var east = (Math.cos(degRad(deg)) * dist );
  return east;
}

// northing calculation functions
function north(deg, dist) {
  var north = (Math.sin(degRad(deg)) * dist);
  return north;
}

//calling functions and out putting the results
document.write("easting equals  " + east(document.getElementById("Ang"),document.getElementById("Dist")) + "<br>");

document.write("northing equals  " + north(document.getElementById("Ang"),document.getElementById("Dist")));
```

```html
<!--This is the page elements to input the angle and distance-->

  <fieldset style="padding: 20px;">
    <legend>Polar to Rectangular calculator</legend>
     Angle: <input type="number" value="14" id="Ang" style="border: 1px solid;"/>
      Distance: <input type="number" value="10" id="Dist" style="border: 1px solid;"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: @isherwood I posted it as a comment because I voted to close the question. I don't think it needs a real answer.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value of the element, like this.

```js
//degrees to radians function
function degRad(deg)
  {
  var rad = ( Math.PI / 180) * deg;
  return rad;
  }

//easting calcualtion function
function east(deg,dist)
  {
  var east = (Math.cos(degRad(deg)) * dist );
  return east;
  }

// northing calculation functions
function north(deg,dist)
  {
    var north = (Math.sin(degRad(deg)) * dist);
    return north;
  }

//CHANGES BELOW

//calling functions and out putting the results
document.write("easting equals  " + east(document.getElementById("Ang").value,document.getElementById("Dist").value) + "<br>");

document.write("northing equals  " + north(document.getElementById("Ang").value,document.getElementById("Dist").value));
```

```html
<!--This is the page elements to input the angle and distance-->

  <fieldset style="padding: 20px;">
    <legend>Polar to Rectangular calculator</legend>
     Angle: <input type="number" value="14" id="Ang" style="border: 1px solid;"/>
      Distance: <input type="number" value="10" id="Dist" style="border: 1px solid;"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
```